# Magento, sort by YES/NO attribute

Tags: php, magento

I have to load a collection of products and sort them for further display.

Originally the collection is sorted by date. That works flawlessly. Now I had to add a new YES/NO attribute to the products. That worked out great as well.

The only thing I wasn't able to figure out is how to sort my collection by this attribute.
The collection would have to be sorted by this new attribute as well as by the date.

I thought this would work:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');

$collection->addAttributeToSelect('YesNoAttr');

$collection->addAttributeToSelect('special_to_date');

$collection->addAttributeToSelect('short_description');

$collection->addAttributeToSelect('image');

$collection->addAttributeToSort('YesNoAttr', 'ASC')->addAttributeToSort('special_to_date', 'ASC');

$products = $collection->load();
```

It doesn't. I also tried to set the order:

```
$collection->setOrder('YesNoAttr','ASC');
```

I tried sorting only by the new attribute, but it didn't work either, so I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with me trying to sort by 2 attributes.

I am trying to solve this now for hours and I'm completely clueless what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI: `$collection->load(true);` will echo the collection query that's being used.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I outputted the generated query and it only adds the ORDER BY part for the date. I tried to remove the date ordering, leaving only $collection->addAttributeToSort('YesNoAttr', 'ASC'). when I did this, the whole ORDER BY part was gone. I assume YES/NO attributes can not be ordered this way?

Comment: Look in the `eav_attribute` DB table and find your attribute's `code` - verify that it matches what you are passing as the first argument to `setOrder()`.

Comment: I checked it and it does match the argument I'm passing to setOrder()

Comment: I should also mention, if I use 

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('YesNoAttr',1);

It works perfect. Only sorting doesn't work, I don't know why :s

Comment: How was this attribute added?

Comment: I assume you want this in 1 instance only and not sitewide? As sorting by custom attribute is native via the admin GUI.

Comment: Yes, I planned to use this in 1 instance only.

I ended up loading 2 product collections, one with the YesNoAttribute filtered to 1, and one with the attribute filtered to 0. It isn't really a solution to this but it does the trick for now.

I'll keep the question open, maybe someone will have a similar problem and find the solution for it.

Thanks for all of your replies.

Answer (score 1):

To add more than one attribute to order you can try to do this:

```
$collection->getSelect()->order('main_table.YesNoAttr asc')
        ->order('main_table.special_to_date asc');
```